# Access router from outside network

Tags: networking, router, switch, scanning

Both routers are connected to the switch. How can I access, scan for open port and get the IP for the router number 2 while I'm in the router number 1?
[image]

Comment: Your question us I'll defined. For a start, routers don't have IP addresses, they have interfaces which have IP addresses - so the first question us do you need the wan or man interface?  The second clarification is are your networks behind NAT, and the third question is what kind of access do you have to the routers and modem?

Comment: I assume that the problem is not getting to the router, but to the computers/devices that are connected to it. If both routers could share the same subnet, there will be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a number of assumptions in this post.

In order to find/attack router 2 from behind router 1, first find its IP address. If you have access to "modem" the easiest way to do this might be to look in its ARP table. This should list the MAC addresses and devices connected to its LAN port, which will help you deduce its IP address. If you can't do that, a simple port scan of the range of IP addresses associated with the WAN subnet should yield a handful if IP addresses which should get you 90£ of the way there - especially as you can deduce the IP address of the modem (is the default gateway/next hop for IP traffic on a traceroute).

Once you know the IP address of router 2 you can simply portscan the IP address associated with it to find any open ports.